# When i use order by desc wih join query why its very slow?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql-order-by

Why this query is slow and when i remove order by its work fine otherwise its very slow

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE DISTINCT A.*, B.Manual_Trigger_Form 
FROM 
cbp_process_instance A, cbp_process B 
WHERE 
A.Process_ID = B.Process_ID 
AND 
B.Process_Status='Active'
ORDER BY Instance_ID DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

Comment: which table does Instance_ID belong to?  Anyway have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: cbp_process is parent table and cbp_process_instance is child table

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: Well he didn't because it's hard to know for sure. You can try the "EXPLAIN" approach and find out the situation with indexes. Or you can try to _optimize_ the table, because it might by heavily fragmented.

Comment: I think we can infer that instance_id belongs to the _instance table.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `DISTINCT` and `*`. Just select the columns you actually want returned. And write out your query using explicit JOIN syntax rather than this implicit comma-join rubbish.

For performance, include an index on (b.Process_ID,b.Process_Status)

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly you suppose to use Inner join. its decrease your query
  execution time and increase query performance.
- try below code

  SELECT A.*, B.Manual_Trigger_Form 
  FROM  cbp_process_instance
  A INNER JOIN cbp_process B
  ON A.Process_ID = B.Process_ID
   WHERE
  B.Process_Status='Active' ORDER BY Instance_ID DESC

Comment: its bi-mistaken added by me